# Debian Server with Postfix and Dovecot + Spam Management

Tags: postfix, spam, dovecot

I currently have an email account that receives TONS of spam because currently I have no filter setup. Is there any way of going through that spam that I am receiving and setup a filter off those hundreds of spam emails instead of just trashing them?

Ratty

Comment: Do you talk about a server solution (as your title implies) or your client software?

Comment: Well yes a server solution but I was wondering if I could use those emails to my advantage of grabbing keywords and all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. Configure amavisd-new with SpamAssassin and use [sa-learn](http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/sa-learn.html) ([here the example scripts](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103002855/http://workaround.org/ispmail-contributions#Spamlearnscripts)) to populate your spam database. Afterwards, continue to re-run this script maybe daily or so to keep current. This is a [sample tutorial](http://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny/amavis-filtering-spam-and-viruses) to getting started.

Comment: Thank you weeheavy I will have to take a look at that soon! Just a quick question, what are your thoughts about ASSP in comparison to the solution you listed above?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I have no experience with ASSP but the features described on their website look good at least.